# Create multiple items like on Ranker.com when creating a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I need to create a form like on [Ranker.com](http://www.ranker.com/) where a user can create a list. My problem is that I cannot add multiple items.

I tried `.clone().appendTo()` with divs, but when they create new div, the title that I insert in'new item' input, duplicates and I have 2-3 divs with the title from first + another text.
[Here is link to Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bLsYS/)

<sub>I found solution for this problem. Please see at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/br_v/eGWpX/1/)</sub>

Comment: Hi there welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Us SOers like using jsfiddle.net to show demonstrations :)

Comment: Thanks Sam, I will provide a link to jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just generate a new textbox instead of using clone() since clone clones the whole thing(value of the textbox, name, id and any attribute that you can think of).
To generate a new textbox you can use this code:

```
var new_txt = $('<input>').attr({'type' : 'text'});
```

You can assign more attributes to the input by separating each attribute with commas:

```
$('<input>').attr({'type' : 'text', 'name' : 'something'});
```

In order to achieve what you want to do you need a container where you will append the newly generated textbox.

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="txt_item"/>
</div>
```

Then just use the live() method to so that everytime the user press enter on a textbox a new textbox is generated:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type=text]').live('keydown', function(e){
    var new_txt = $('<input>').attr({'type' : 'text'});
    if(e.keyCode == 13){//If user press enter
        new_txt.appendTo('#container').focus(); //append then focus to new textbox
    }
});
</script>
```

As you can see this is a very simple example but you can probably take it from here. Goodluck!